# strongloop: example of combining a where filter with an order filter?

Tags: strongloop

In the docs Strongloop does not talk about a common condition: using a WHERE filter with a Order filter.

Example:  `Customers WHERE name='John' ORDER BY 'birthdate' DESC LIMIT 5`

```
Customers.find({where:{'userId':'John'},{order:'birthdate DESC',limit:5}},...
```

Anyone have the right syntax? It runs but it's not giving the right answer.  It's not applying the ORDER filter nor the limit filter.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Order and limit are two properties of the object send to find, you merged limit and order into a subdocument. You should use:

```
  Customers.find({ 
    where: { 'userId': 'John' },
    order: 'birthdate DESC', //can take array of string if multiple order
    limit: 5
  });
```

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Order+filter